# Creative Paper Folding

Tags: paper-folding

Shown below is 6x5 grid drawn on a paper with various numbers (1 to 9) and letters filling the 30 boxes.

[image: Top row: V, 4, 6, L, 1, 5. Second row: 2, 8, 3, 1, 8, 9. Third row: 6, 4, C, 8, 5, 3. Fourth row: 4, 1, 9, 3, 2, 7. Fifth row: 3, X, 8, 1, 5, D.]

By folding the paper grid 5 times or less can you get to a 3x3 grid showing only the numbers 1 to 9. The folded paper should look like

[image: 3-by-3 grid of empty boxes]

with the numbers 1 to 9 that you can read directly. All numbers must show up on the 3x3 grid with 1 number per box. Order not necessary. The answer with the least number of foldings will be accepted. Folding only.

Some creative thinking may be needed.

Comment: Yes. Back is blank. I is one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I have a solution that uses

> **4**

folds.

The key to this puzzle is to realize that:

> many of the digits can be inverted and still be valid.  This is true for 1, 2, 5, and 8, while 6 and 9 will be valid but swap values. Additionally, while most of the letters cannot appear in the final grid, the L is special, as it looks just like a seven when flipped. Thus, we can use it in place of the seven, which would otherwise have forced us to use the only 7 in the grid.  This allows us to create solutions where some of the cells are "upside-down", but will still appear as a valid digit.

Folds:

> [image: folds]
>  Where all folds are away from the viewer.

Result:

> If we look at the resulting paper, we end up with:
>  [image: wrong]
>  Which clearly isn't the solution.

> However, if we flip the paper around, we end up with:
>  [image: right]
>  Which looks a lot more like our desired result.

Comment: Jung n terng jnl bs nccebnpuvat naq fbyivat. Irel jryy qbar!

Comment: Lbh fubhyq nyfb zragvba gung 9 vf vairegrq 6!

Comment: @DrD I added a bit more explanation about the nature of rot13(vairegrq qvtvgf).